# Best UI Library to use with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, yui

What do you guys recommend for a UI library to use with jQuery. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) seems to have less widgets compared to other frameworks. I've been playing around lately with the [Dojo Toolkit](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/) which seems pretty nice so far, and I know that there is always the [Yahoo! User Interface](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), but is there anything else?

I also need to consider licensing, something that can be distributed with Open Source software licensed under the BSD license as well as internal-use software.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those other "ui libraries" depend on entire other frameworks. If you're using Prototype, choose Scriptaculous. If you're using Dojo, use Dijit.

If you're using jQuery, really, use jQuery UI. You can style the jQuery UI "widgets" a number of different ways; take a look at the Theme Roller Gallery: http://themeroller.com/

What do you mean by lack of maturity and polish?

Comment: +1 on your comment about maturity and polish.  jQuery UI is very well fleshed out from a functionality point of view -- and you can achieve whatever visual effects you want.

Comment: Compared to Dojo and YUI I don't think the themes for jQuery UI look all that great. They are better than anything I can come up with, but a lot of the themes seemed like they were designed by programmers, not designers.

Comment: Let's deconstruct that: You've got widgets, the user interface controls like calendars, sliders, etc., and then you've got how those widgets look. jQuery calls that a Theme, YUI calls it a Skin, it's the same thing.

Take a look at http://themeroller.com/

Comment: If you can create your own theme to use with jQuery UI, then how is the lack of "polish" on the pre-packaged themes a knock against the library at all?

Comment: @matt b: He just said that he couldn't make anything like that, so obviously he wants good themes *built-in*.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the jQuery UI widget's in various stages. Some are mature. Some are less so.

The beauty of jQuery is that it's great at not interfering with anything else, **so I like to use jQuery with YUI** for my UI widgets. YUI is mature, professional looking "out of the box", and thoroughly tested against all A grade browsers. I can't say the same for all the jQuery UI widgets.

Comment: Just took a look at YUI2 and YUI3. Seems cool but terrifyingly huge. It also seems be a general purpose web library. Why would you use jquery at all?

Answer (score 0):

jquery tools - http://jquerytools.org/demos/ is another option worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend according to current trends to use Twitter  Bootstrap and it contains all the required elements.

[twitter.github.com/bootstrap/](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: Not really a JavaScript Library, in fact just a couple of plugins based on bootstraps themes.